# Замкнутое слайд-шоу с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!

Будьте добры, подскажите, как сделать замкнутое слайд-шоу.

Что имеем: **http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/m3Q5r/14/**

Необходимо сделать следующее: за последней фотографией идет снова первая, и переход от последней к первой, осуществляется также как другие переходы.

Не слишком сумбурная формулировка?

На сколько я понимаю, необходимо задать условие... как то так:

```
var x = $('.innerSlide')

x.each(function(i) {
if( x[i] == x.length ){}
```

В общем, запутался я...

Может подскажет кто...?

Заранее благодарю

Comment: @Barton, спасибо. Буду разбираться что и как...

А возможно в доп. настройках задать автоматическую прокрутку (на сколько я понимаю, - через setInterval())? Вот только каким образом это осуществить?

Comment: Да можно, добавить параметр, например circular и timer. И смотреть, если он true, то установить интервал и писать клик в право раз в timer мс.

Comment: обновил код - http://jsfiddle.net/Barton89/sbbdF/2/

Comment: @Barton, огромное Вам спасибо за терпение и помощь. Плюсую по всем комментариям.

По коду у меня есть кое-какие вопросы. Хочу прокомментировать каждую строку с пояснениями... Не могли бы Вы проверить то, что я накомментирую, поправить если что не так... Напишу чуть позже,- семья требует внимания. 

Заранее благодарю.

С уважением, Александр

Comment: Обращайтесь, почта в профиле, если что - пишите в Gtalk, так будет удобнее

Comment: @Barton

Юрий, посмотрите пожалуйста - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/sbbdF/3/

P.s. В Вашем профиле почта не указана, поэтому пишу сюда.

P.s2 Заметил баг. Если очень часто нажимать на стрелку, то слайдер зависает. С чем это может быть связано?

P.s3 Да, и еще забыл спросить, 

    var first = $('.'+opts.placeholders+' img:first');

Зачем так сложно? разве нельзя вот так

    var first = $('.innerSlide img:first');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Велосипед это конечно хорошо, но зачем изобретать то, то уже написано?
Есть замечательный плагин для jQuery - [scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/easing.html)

Comment: А как быть если хочется изобрести... понять как это работает. Может кто-то писал нечто подобное...

Comment: В таком случае рассмотрите вариант с клонированием крайних элементов.
С помощью скрипта создаете перед первым элементом клон последнего, после последнего - клон первого. Таким образом когда вы находитесь на последнем и нажимаете далее - слайдер плавно переходит далее, после окончания анимации переходите на 1й элемент(не клон) и без аннимации, чтоб пользователь ничего не увидел. Как-то так

Comment: @Barton, помогите пожалуйста с условием, столько уже всего перепробовал, но... безуспешно. Вот например:

    if( $('.innerSlide img').next() == false ) {...}

Comment: Это что вы делаете? ищете последний слайд или это уже когда работает слайд шоу? Крайним клонированным элементам задайте класс, пример "cloned" так будет легче понять что находимся на последнем

Comment: @Barton, посмотрите пожалуйста: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/m3Q5r/51/

Пока сделал обработку нажатия по rightSlide, почти получилось, но работает не совсем так как хотелось бы.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сие довести до корректно работающего состояния.

Comment: Вы немного не правильно сделали. Надо добавлять клоны не в момент нажатия на стрелки, а в самом начале, при инициализации сладейра. И тогда по стрелкам вам надо только смотреть что активно и куда двигать слайды. Оформите все в виде плагина, будет проще. Код поковыряю завтра с утра.

Comment: @Barton, к сожалению с написанием плагинов не сталкивался. Завтра с утра поищу информацию, как их(плагины) оформлять.

По коду: вынес переменные last и cloned, а также само клонирование в определение, то есть туда-же где вызываются функции leftSlide и rightSlide, но результат все-равно не радует.... http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/m3Q5r/59/

Comment: Для того, чтобы слайд-шоу начиналось с первого изображения а не со второго, добавил в начало еще одно изображение. Но думаю, что это не лучшее решение...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Barton89/sbbdF/ - вот набросал плагин, посмотрите.