# Как сделать обычный слайдер?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не срабатывает скрипт, который написал. Вот есть блок с картинками, надо сделать слайдер, обычный, без управления. Картинки в списке li лежат в одну линию, сам блок имеет ширину 10000px, надо, чтоб этот список проматывал себя на 520px, это ширина картинки. Но когда последняя картинка, она перематывалась на первую. Это надо сделать с помощью метода each. Ну кто разбирается поймет. Блок, с нем список, и в каждом li лежит картинка.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('блок с картинками img').each(function () {
            $('блок с картинками img').children('блок с картинками img').css('left', '520px');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Надо, чтобы, когда последняя картинка, блок начинал с начала, надо if else применить, но я не знаю, каков порядок прописывания в коде. В css left блок стоит релатив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177312/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4-%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery).  Смотрите в комментах в вопросу готовый пример.