# Слайдер на js

Tags: slider, javascript

Всем привет, ребят. Перелазил по Инету, нашел кучу слайдеров, но они не подходят. Некоторые кривые, некоторые вообще не работают и т.д.

Нужен примерной такой: http://bifot.ru/cloud/slider.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kotweb.ru/for_web_developers/must_have/38-101-slayder-i-slaydshou-dlya-sayta-na-jquery-css-shikarno-prosto-shikarno.html - из этого можно выбрать и подогнать под свои нужды.

Answer (score 0):

Был подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177312/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4-%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery). Также могу посоветовать NivoSlider или Scrollable от jQuery UI. 
К сожалению, ваша ссылка не открывается.